How to show the quantities of a column depending on the maximum or minimum values within another column in Scilab?
My problem is related to unfamiliarness with the program as a whole. An attempt has been made to display the values of time at the maximum and minimum values, but I'm not sure how to approach the problem. I have successfully displayed the maximum and minimum values, but I have not been able to link values from another column to those quantities.
The problem reads:
"a. Read the data file (using the fscanfMat('SENSOR.txt') command) and print the number
of sensors and the number of seconds of data contained in the file. Remember, column 1
does not contain sensor data; it contains time data. ( Hint: Use the size function.)
b. Find both the maximum value and the minimum value recorded on each sensor.
Determine at what times they occurred.
c. Find the mean and standard deviation for each sensor and all the data values collected."
The SENSOR.txt is:
0.    70.6432   68.347    72.3469   67.6751   73.1764

73.2823   65.7819   65.4822   71.8548   66.9929
64.1609   72.4888   70.1794   73.6414   72.7559
67.697    77.4425   66.8623   80.5608   64.5008
68.6878   67.2676   72.677    63.2135   70.43
63.9342   65.7662   72.644    64.8869   59.9772
63.4028   68.7683   68.9815   75.1892   67.5346
74.6561   73.3151   59.7284   68.051    72.3102
70.0562   65.729    70.6628   63.0937   68.395
66.7743   63.9934   77.9647   71.5777   76.1828
74.0286   69.4007   75.0921   77.7662   66.8436
71.1581   69.6735   62.098    73.5395   58.3739
65.0512   72.4265   69.6067   79.7869   63.8418
76.6979   67.0225   66.5917   72.5227   75.2782
71.4475   69.2517   64.8772   79.3226   69.4339
77.3946   67.8262   63.8282   68.3009   71.8961
75.6901   69.6033   71.444    64.3011   74.721
66.5793   77.6758   67.8535   68.9444   59.3979
63.5403   66.9676   70.279    75.9512   66.7766
69.6354   63.2632   68.1606   64.419    66.4785

Part (b) the area I am having issues with is writing code that both finds the maximum and minimum values within each column (I have completed), but then to also include the time values (column 1) at which each of those values occur. These values are then meant to be put into an matrix and displayed.
An example of my current code is below and I would greatly appreciate some assistance. Thanks!
Current Code
I tried two different methods. The first being to display each column as its own variable, but this seemed ridiculous and overly complicated. I then tired to establish a [big,place(2:6)]=max(:,(2:6)) to identify the location of each maximum(or minimum) value and take that value as a variable and then display based off of the variable I defined previously. I expected this to work, but I run into the issue of "Submatrix Incorrectly Defined".

The link to your code doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

I recommend you too look at the find function in the Scilab help, which gives you the "true" indices (of a vector or matrix), therefore in a vector V the index of the maxium value (or values if the same max value is repeated!) is:
i = find( V == max( V ) );

The corresponding time in vector T is then t=T(i). Of course you can use submatrix indices of the full original data matrix:
i = find( M(:,2) == max( M(:,2) ) );
t = M(i,1);

(If you find the answer useful, please do not forget to accept it, so others will see that your problem is solved.)

Here is a working proposal:
Data = fscanfMat('SENSOR.txt');
data = Data(:, 2:$);
[M ,kM] = max(data, 'r');
kM = Data(kM,1)';
[m, km] = min(data, 'r');
km = Data(km, 1)';
average = mean(data, 'r');
spread = stdev(data, 'r');

[M ; kM ; m ; km ; average ; spread]

yielding
--> [M ; kM ; m ; km ; average ; spread]
 ans  =
   77.3946     77.6758     77.9647     80.5608     76.1828  
   15.         17.         9.          3.          9.       
   63.4028     63.2632     59.7284     63.0937     58.3739  
   6.          19.         7.          8.          11.      
   69.72589    69.10054    68.86801    71.22993    68.264865
   4.5471074   3.9223221   4.4091651   5.7190233   5.2411597

